# Sourcing the environment vaariable input from script file is not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell

I'm having a file with the following inputs

filename:inputs

ABC=10

export ABC

When i try to source the input file from command prompt,its exporting the environment variable properly and it is working as expected..

```
  #echo $ABC

  #10
```

Whereas when i try to source the input from script file,it's not exporting the enviroment variable

test.sh(/bin/sh)
       source /path/inputs

```
 #./test.sh
 #echo $ABC
 #
```

Could someone help me how to get rid of these issues?

Comment: It should be `source test.sh`

Answer (score 2):

the problem is, you should in your terminal execute:

```
source test.sh
```

instead of

```
./test.sh
```

Because if you do `./test.sh` the execution will be in a sub-shell.

Comment: Not entirely correct. Posix shell does not know about a command called `source` (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html)). The correct way to source a file is described [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html).

Answer (score 1):

You claim that you are sourcing your script, but I can not see in your posting where you would do this. Neither

```
#./test.sh
```

nor

```
./test.sh
```

would source a file. The correct command is

```
. ./test.sh
```